# Cordova angularJS list item click, redirect to list item detail page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, visual-studio-2013

Let me explain about my situation: I have a listview which contains movies. All those movies contains and movieId. When I click on a movie in the listview, I want to be redirected to the detail page of that movie. I've already tried a lot of things, but I don't seem to use the right method. So that is the reason of my question.

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {


    $stateProvider
      .state('search', {
          url: '/search',
          templateUrl: 'search.html'
      })
      .state('settings', {
          url: '/settings',
          templateUrl: 'settings.html'
      })
      .state('tabs', {
          url: "/tab",
          abstract: true,
          templateUrl: "tabs.html"
      })

      .state('tabs.home', {
          url: "/home",
          views: {
              'home-tab': {
                  templateUrl: "home.html",
                  controller: 'HomeTabCtrl'
              }
          }
      })

         .state('tabs.movies', {
             url: "/movies",
             views: {
                 'home-tab': {
                     templateUrl: "partials/movies.html"
                 }
             }
         })

        .state('tabs.movies.details', {
            url: "/movies/:id",


            views: {
                'home-tab': {
                    templateUrl: "partials/movieDetails.html"
                }
            }
        })

      .state('tabs.login', {
          url: "/login",
          views: {
              'home-tab': {
                  templateUrl: "partials/login.html"
              }
          }
      })
        .state('tabs.logout', {
            url: "/logout",
            views: {
                'home-tab': {
                    templateUrl: "partials/logout.html"
                }
            }
        })
      .state('tabs.facts2', {
          url: "/facts2",
          views: {
              'home-tab': {
                  templateUrl: "facts2.html"
              }
          }
      })
      .state('tabs.about', {
          url: "/about",
          views: {
              'about-tab': {
                  templateUrl: "about.html"
              }
          }
      })
      .state('tabs.navstack', {
          url: "/navstack",
          views: {
              'about-tab': {
                  templateUrl: "nav-stack.html"
              }
          }
      })
      .state('tabs.contact', {
          url: "/contact",
          views: {
              'contact-tab': {
                  templateUrl: "contact.html"
              }
          }
      });


    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/tab/home");

});
```

movies.html

```
<ion-view title="Movies">
    <ion-content>
        <ion-list ng-controller="MovieCtrl" ng-init="get()">
            <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items">
                <a href="#/tab/movies/{{item.movieId}}">
                    <h2>{{item.movieTitle}}</h2>
                    <p>{{item.movieDescription}}</p>
                </a>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

MovieDetails.html

```
<ion-view title="Movie details">
    <ion-content>
        <div>
            <h2>{{item.movieTitle}}</h2>
            <p>{{item.movieId}}</p>
            <p>{{item.movieDescription}}</p>
        </div>              
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

MovieCtrl.js

```
app.controller('MoviesCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.get = function () {
        $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'http://xxx.xxx.xx/api/movies' }).success(function (data) {
            $scope.items = data;
        });
    };

});
```

After I click on a list item the page directs to the Movie details, but it shows an empty page. I'd expect that the field were filled.

I hope I explained it cleary. If that is not the case please tell me so I can edit this post!

Thanks!

Comment: You didn't mentioned what is your issue, does it go to details or not?

Comment: Added it, thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a point. You are settings the result in your `$scope` as `items`, but you use `item` in your view. If you expect to receive more result, you should use `ng-repeat`, otherwise, rename it to `$scope.item` and you should see the result.
To use with `ng-repeat`, you need to change the `div` to following

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <h2>{{item.movieTitle}}</h2>
  <p>{{item.movieId}}</p>
  <p>{{item.movieDescription}}</p>
</div>
```